# ShowcaseView is shown under the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-actionbar, showcaseview

As you can see, the ShowcaseView appears under the ActionBar

[image]

Can anyone point out the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ShowcaseView 5.3.0 or later, this is the new default behaviour (as users are now expected to use AppCompatActivity with a Toolbar).

You'll want to add this line to your ShowcaseView.Builder creation:

```
builder.useDecorViewAsParent()
```

Which should fix the issue!